# PHP jpgraph - how to give space for each statistics?

Tags: php

We have displayed the student statistics for each departments in our application.  Everything is working fine for us. But the designs are getting overlap for each student stats.

FYI, See the below screenshot

[image]

Here the stats % 0.3 and 1.0 are getting overlapped.

**Code:**

```
$color=array("#5c61fb","#bf7a7c","#f46163","#f4fafb","#f4fa63",
               "#f4c463","#5cfa63","#bc74f2","#66e1e3","#f4a0ce");
$graph = new PieGraph(750,400,"auto");
$graph->SetShadow();
$graph->SetBackgroundImage('logo.jpg',BGIMG_COPY);
$graph->legend->SetFillColor('lightblue@0.7');
$graph->title->Set("Résultat $_GET[annee] $_GET[bourse]");

//$p1 = new PiePlot3D($arrayx_val);     
$p1 = new PiePlot3D($arrayy);
$p1->SetSize(0.5);
$p1->SetCenter(0.4);
$p1->SetSliceColors($color);
$p1->SetLegends($arrayx);
$p1->value->SetFormat('%.1f%%');
//$p1->value->SetFormat("%.5d%%");      //$p1->SetLabelType(PIE_VALUE_ABS);
$p1->SetLabelPos(1);
$p1->value->HideZero();
//$p1->value->SetFont( FF_FONT1, FS_BOLD);
//$p1->value->SetMargin(50);
$p1->SetLabelMargin(20);
//$p1->SetShadow(); 
$graph->footer->left->SetFont( FF_FONT2, FS_BOLD);
$graph->footer->left->Set("Exclusion : ".$array_footer[0]."  Abandon : ".$array_footer[1]."  Démission : ".$array_footer[2]."");
$graph->footer-> center-> SetColor("red");
$graph->Add($p1);
$graph->Stroke();
```

So kindly assist our request and how to avoid this overlapping design as per the screenshot.

Thanks.